# need for unmap signalmapper?

Tags: qt4

A piece of my code:

```
signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
for(int i=0; i<result.count(); ++i)
{
    drawpushb(result.at(i).ptr,pushb.at(i),ratio,0); // draw pic in pushb.
    grid->addWidget(pushb.at(row*opregel+c),row,col);
    connect(pushb.at(i), SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
    signalMapper->setMapping(pushb.at(i), i);

    if(++col==opregel)
    {
       ++row;
       col=0;
    }

    if((row*opregel + col)==totalbuttons)
      break;
}

connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int )),this, SLOT(goto_tab(int )));
```

There is a list of pushbuttons created and they are placed in a gridlayout.
That is placed in a widget and that is put into a qtabwidget.

Ok.
Now that piece of code is executed more than once. My tabwidget is made empty and first the widget that is on that tab, is deleted, so my pushbuttons will be deleted as well. But what happens with the mapper? Those buttons don't exist anymore. And after that a new mapper will be created for the new pushbuttons.
What happens with the old one? Is it still there, doing nothing? 
Should I delete the signalmapper also (how?).

I am new to qt and it sometimes puzzles me what is deleted by QT and what I should delete myself.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete a `QObject` in Qt, all of its children are deleted automatically. So, it will be a good idea to make your signal mapper a child of the widget you delete:

```
class MappedWidget : public QWidget
{
    ...
signals:
    void buttonClicked(int i);

private:
    QList<QPushButton*> buttons;
    QSignalMapper *mapper;
}

MappedWidget::MappedWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    mapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
    ...
    // do mapping here
    ...

    connect(mapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SIGNAL(buttonClicked(int)));
}
```

Later you can connect to the `buttonClicked(int)` signal of this widget. When this widget is deleted, all of its children, including a mapper, will be deleted too.

Comment: Hank, thank you for your reply! I have to digest that first :-). Is the way I do it now, very different from your solution? Now I put all the mapped pushbuttons in a widget and that is put into the qtabwidget. When I remove that widget, are the pushbuttons not deleted with the mapper? I heve to delete my widget by hand of course, before removing the tab. I like to understand it but i takes time.

Comment: When you place your buttons on a widget, they will be deleted automatically when that widget is deleted.